# Collapse 2D ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I have an object which contains a dynamically allocated 2D `ArrayList`.

It has a getter: `ArrayList<Integer> getList()`

I'd like a function to collapse the 2D `ArrayList` into a 1D `ArrayList`. Does Java have such a thing or am I stuck doing this:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getList(){
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < list_.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < list_.get(i).size(); j++){
            result.add(list_.get(i).get(j));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer>`, not `ArrayList<int>`, and you can use `addAll` instead of your `j` `for` loop.

Comment: @rgettman Thanks, fixed... too much C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without Java 8, you do have to use loops. using `addAll(..)` does get rid of one of them though.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getList(){
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(ArrayList<Integer> i : list_){
        result.addAll(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Also, generic types such as ArrayList must be object types, hence Integer, not int.

Comment: @JBNizet I've accepted this solution, but yours would be my preference if I was on Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

With Java 8:

```
return _list.stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Before Java 8, a loop is needed.